# Populate Backbone Marionette Views with data from Mongoose using Express Route

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, marionette

Im trying to fetch the data/api using a node/express route with data stored in mongo/mongoose and show it inside Backbone Marionette...

The route im using is this:

```
enter code here`app.get('/cats', function(req, res){
Cat.find({}, function (err, docs) {
res.send(docs);
  });
});
```

2) When I go to localhost:3000/cats, I get the json working as:

```
[
{
"__v": 0,
"_id": "51318ce9a7ff43f808000003",
"catname": "Jonas"
},
{
"catname": "Justin",
"_id": "51416268a8225e7413000001",
"__v": 0
},
{
"catname": "Bobby",
"_id": "51416268a8225e7413000001",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

3) Now how can I have the collection/model/itemview/etc use this json data from my db?

I usually get this far:

```
MyCat = Backbone.Model.extend({});

MyCats = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: MyCat,
url: '/cats'
});

CatView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
template: "#cats-template",
tagName: 'li',
className: 'cat'
});

AngryCatsView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
tagName: "ul",
id: "cats",
template: "#cats-template",
itemView: CatView,

appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
collectionView.$("ul").append(itemView.el);
}
});
```

But then im not sure which type of initializer to use.
I've seen examples with hardcoded json, but none from a db.

Comment: Problem was this...

var thecats= myCats();
thecats.fetch();

Hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in the code you've posted have you actually fetched your collection from the server.

Attempt this:

```
var catCollection = new MyCats();
catCollection.fetch();

var angryCatsView = new AngryCatsView({collection: catCollection});
angryCatsView.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for your situation but on your collection, add a parse method that accepts your data.  You may have a nested array that Backbone isn't able to retrieve the internal data from.

```
parse: function(data) {
  return data[0];
}
```

I would add a debug point inside this parse method to see if the data being passed in is nesting the data.

Comment: You didn't try the code as written did you? You'll have to put in your own data plus however it is returned. In my application, ServiceStack returns the data nested into another object so I have to do something like this.  return data.CoreDataList;  I just put data[0] just as one idea. You'll have to debug in the parse function to see what is being passed in.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I've been reading up on different tutorials, but have been unable to figure it out.I tried parse in both the collection and compositeview. What i'm trying to do is a restful route similar to this, http//jsfiddle.net/w3r5B/

Comment: The jsfiddle example is not pulling up in the browser. Can you repost the link?

Comment: I figured it out, just had to fetch the collection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was this... 
var thecats= myCats(); 
thecats.fetch(); 
Hope it helps someone