# connecting mongodb, backbone, grunt task & heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, gruntjs

I'v created the basic front end structure of my app and set it up for deployment to Heroku.  I'v followed the heroku getting started (with node.js) tutorial and all seems to be working fine as I can see it running on my localhost and also online.  I'v also successfully installed MongoDB using the express driver and I connect to it from an index.js file sitting on the root. I can see this connecting successfully from the console logs in my git bash terminal.

My backbone app sits in a folder called "Public" on the root, which Grunt minifys into 1 file which gets placed in a folder called 'lib' on the root.

I'd like to know how I can access my db from within the backbone views?

I'v followed this example: [Populate Backbone Marionette Views with data from Mongoose using Express Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399561/populate-backbone-marionette-views-with-data-from-mongoose-using-express-route)
but I don't see the connection with index.js and the backbone views and how they interact.  I'm also confused as to where the /cats json file sits?

My folder structure is like so:

```
public
--css
--fonts
--img
--js
--lib
--scss

lib
--minified-javascript-app.js

index.js
Gruntfile.js
```

my index.js file looks like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  console.log("mongoose: connected");
});

var myDbSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

myDbSchema.methods.logName = function () {
  var name = this.name
    ? "The name of the site is " + this.name
    : "This one don't have a name"
  console.log(name);
}

Cats = mongoose.model('Cats', myDbSchema);

var dublinCat = new Cats({ name: 'Catty1' });
console.log(dublinCat.name);

var londonCat = new Cats({ name: 'Catty1' });
londonCat.logName();

londonCat.save(function (err, cats) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log("All sites: ",cats);
});

//end of mongoos db stuff

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure on how you do things on nodejs.

To fetch data required for backbone views, you have to use models/collections.

**Model:**

A Backbone is a representation of your domain object that forms the basis of your project.You will be defining an **urlRoot** property for each backbone model. This will identify the server side resource(a restful service) that will return data from the server. The backbone model provides implicit methods to fetch and save data. When you invoke fetch method from the model, a get request is passed to the server using the urlRoot with the id (the unique id for your domain object) appended to the url.

EG:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Defined if the name of the domain object identifier is different
    // from 'id'
    idAttribute : "userId",
    urlRoot : '/rest/user'
});

var user = new User();
user.set('userId',1);
user.fetch({
    success : function(model, response, options) {
       // handle success 
    },
    error : function(model, response, options) {
      // handle failure
    }
});
```

Say that my application is running on 'http://localhost/usermanagement', then GET request url will be as follows:

http://localhost/usermanagement/rest/user/1

So on your node server you will need to create and register a method that can handle request 'rest/user' and type 'GET'. Similarly you will need registered methods for POST,PUT and DELETE for the same URL to handle save() and destroy().

**Collection:**

A Backbone collection is a set of models. For each collection you can define an 'url' property that you can use to fetch data from the server. For instance, you can create a collection for a list of users and fetch them from the server.

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#exercise-2-book-library---your-first-restful-backbone.js-app

There is a simple and a good example of backbone with nodejs in the above link.

On the design side it is good to have an EventBus (a custom javascript object) that does the job of creating the models/collections required for a view and does the fetch. It then creates a view and passes the fetched model/collection to it which renders the data.

1. Backbone router handles the client side routing and delegates to an EventBus.
2. The EventBus creates the model/collections required for the view and does the fetch.
3. After the fetch it also creates the Backbone view object and passes the fetched model/collections to it.
4. The view renders the data.

Comment: Hi Balaji, Thanks for the reply.  I understand backbone models and collections and how to retrieve data in the method you are explaining.  My problem is with my MongoDB setup.  When I call my db from my backbone views & models it says my "Schema" / "DB model name" is undefined.  I need to make my connection to mongoos, and require express etc. in the index.js  but how to I then call my DB from my Backbone models.  If I define a urlRoot, where is the url point to?  It can't be localhost because when I deploy it online to heroku that wont work..

Comment: 'urlRoot' will be the path that your REST resource has been mapped to. So if app is your 'express' object instance and you specify '/rest/user' in urlRoot, then you should have something like app.get('/rest/user/:id',callback), In the callback you connect to your db,fetch data and return it back.

Comment: If your backbone client code and your server side code are running on different environments, then you should use $.ajaxPrefilter and override the url attribute in options with exact base url on which your server side code is running.By default,Backbone will append the urlRoot with current url base on which your client code is running.

Comment: Ok I believe I'v missed out the steps I need to take that creates a REST service.  I'll look into how to do this with mongodb.  Thanks Balaji